# Refresh desktop application

Tags: spring-mvc

We are building an application based on Spring MVC and it is a link from another desktop application. After closing the popup application we need to refresh the desktop client.

We are trying to make an ajax call and refresh it. Let me know if any of you have encountered the same problem.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '${testInfo.refreshUrl}',
    type: 'GET',
    data:'custno=' + '${testInfo.customerNumber}' + '&app=CustomerOverview',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {},
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```

`refreshURL` contains the value of localhost url of the desktop client.

Comment: What exactly the problem is?

Comment: actually the request is not hitting the desktop client